# iOS 7 tutorial to learn iOS 8?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, ios8, xcode6

I am a beginner iOS developer. I bought a book on iOS 7 development. Now Apple released iOS 8 and the new Xcode 6. Can I still use the iOS 7 development book and code apps on the new Xcode 6 with iOS 8 SDK? Also, if I code app with iOS 8 SDK does that mean I'm creating an iOS 8 app or do I have to implement something? I'm confused!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah; you can specifically target just iOS 7 within Xcode, even if you are using the iOS 8 SDK:

[image]

(as long as the iOS SDK >= deployment target, it will be OK).

Answer (score 0):

You'll be pleased to hear tht everything you'll learn for iOS 7 still applies in iOS 8. In the new version of Xcode a lot has been added, but not a lot has been drastically changed as was the case in previous versions.

I've started developing apps just before iOS 5 came out, and Apple spent an entire year making significant changes that made tutorials and books seem forever outdated. Since the introduction of Xcode 5 and iOS 7 this was no longer an issue. Swift is the big new addition, it's a new programming language of can use instead (or alongside) Objective C. It's a good idea to learn it at one point, but not essential in the beginning.

So yes, your iOS 7 book is a good starting point and it's still relevant.